# how to align logo and header title on same line in a responsive site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align a header title and logo in same line.
On desktop and laptop it looks great but on mobile the logo overlap the title that you won't see all the text clearly.

Below here are my code.

```css
.page-header {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 224px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.page-header #title {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.page-header #logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<header class="page-header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fix-top" role="Navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        
        <a href="#"><img src="images/dove.png" id="logo"></a>
        <div id="title">Birdwatching</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use absolute positioning if you don't want overlapping. Also you can use here flexbox approach, so you can remove your floats here and move elements in more natural order in HTML. Demo:

```css
header .navbar-header {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* its immediate children will be flex-items */ 
  display: flex;
  /* doing some normalising due to default bootstrap styles */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.navbar-header > a {
  /* move to the right */
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar-header > button {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.page-header {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 224px;
  display: block;
}

.page-header #title {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.page-header #logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<header class="page-header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fix-top" role="Navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div id="title">Birdwatching</div>

        <a href="#"><img src="images/dove.png" id="logo"></a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I copied the code you wrote and paste it but it didn't work perfect like yours, the button is showing outside the width of page-header.

Comment: @EvaristusIhezurumba Are you sure you copied the same HTML and CSS?

Comment: @VadimOvchinikov copied both HTML and CSS it looks great but on Mobile the toggle button is outside the page-header width. is there anything i have to do to make it look great and responsive in mobile

Comment: @EvaristusIhezurumba It depends on screen width. If screen width is very small you can apply and there is no chance that children can fit container then you need to apply some additional styling (remove paddings, reduce font-size etc) via media queries for that small screens.

Comment: @VadimOvchinikov pls help me the code actually i am just a beginner

Comment: @EvaristusIhezurumba It's OK that you are a beginner. Please try to understand how it works. When your children of block `.navbar-header` are less than windows width they "overflow", is this clear? So to prevent overflow there are a lot of scenarios (provide scrollbar, hide some items, shrink some items, rearrange them etc) and I can't provide you just a solution here. Please google and learn some basics like "media queries", "CSS overflow" etc.